# How can I temporally write a file to the filesystem but actually hold it on RAM?

Tags: linux, file, ram

I have a server that receives a file in a HTTP request, I'd like to make that file available to another process but I don't want the I/O overhead of writing that file to disk.

Are there any directories in linux that are actually mapped to RAM, so the process I start can access a path as is were a normal file?

I know that if I do this in a normal file, then there is a good chance that the file wont actually be flushed to disk because of cache, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are also caching libraries like Redis that are often used for this type of problem

Comment: IPC. E.g.: shared memory, socket.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have no control of the other program, only a command-line API that receives a filepath as argument.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Answer (score 3):

There are no guaranteed locations that are backed by RAM, but [it's not particularly hard to convert `/tmp` to be backed by RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount) if you have enough of RAM to spare. Given that [`/tmp` is cleaned out on boot anyway](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up), it's an ideal choice for a RAM disk, since data loss due to power loss doesn't matter; the data would have been cleaned on boot anyway.

Comment: *Given that `/tmp` is cleaned out on boot anyway* [Not necessarily](http://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared).  Although I agree, no one should *depend* on contents in `/tmp` surviving *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to create a RAM disk (as per [these instructions](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux)):

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t ramfs -o size=512m ramfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to make sure a specific file is/stays in RAM, you can use vmtouch (https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/). However, the file will be written to disk.